# RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ros, gpio

My aim is to write a Ros node that publishes the data received from a Sonar installed on my robot car. I use a Raspberry Pi 4B as a microcontroller.Therefore i setted first the raspi pin as out/in for the sonar with the bash command:
`$ echo 27 > /sys/class/gpio/export; $ echo out >/sys/class/gpio/gpio27/direction` and finally i check if the pin 27 has been setted as output `$ cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/direction`  that outputs **out**. Now, when i run the following python code trying to access this pin, i get the following error: ***RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT***.
It looks like the pin isn't setted. Please note:

1. I didn't use the GPIO.setup() method cause the pin is already setted.
2. I don't want to use the sudo command on the python script because this has to be runned with the rosrun command
3. I setted as well the pin 22 as in
4. I tried all conventions for pin numbering: BCM, WiringPi and BOARD
5. Python code:

````
#!/usr/bin/env pyhton
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

class Sonar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.period = 0.00001
        self.trigger_pin = 27
        self.echo_pin = 22

        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        #GPIO.setup(self.trigger_pin, GPIO.OUT)
        #GPIO.setup(self.echo_pin, GPIO.IN)

    def activateTrigger(self):
        GPIO.output(self.trigger_pin, 1)
        time.sleep(self.period)
        GPIO.output(self.trigger_pin, 0)

    def waitEcho(self, value):
        while GPIO.input(self.echo_pin) == value:
            pass

    def getDistance(self):
        measurements = []
        measurements_num = 3
        for i in range(measurements_num):
            # I activate the trigger
            self.activateTrigger()
            # I am waiting for the echo to turn 1 and i mesure the time ECHO=1
            self.waitEcho(0)
            start = time.time()
            self.waitEcho(1)
            stop = time.time() 
            pulse_len = (stop - start)
            distance_cm = pulse_len*17000
            measurements.append(distance_cm)
        # return the average of the measurements
        return int(sum(measurements)/measurements_num)

if __name__=='__main__':
    s = Sonar()
    print('Getting distance...') ```
````